# XNA / MonoGame - render transparent background using stencil buffer problem (3d)

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame, transparency

I'm trying to render 3d texture quads with the following properties:

1. With lighting (rule out "AlphaTestEffect").
2. Transparent background (no opacity levels, just binary opaque or transparent).
3. No ordering, eg, I don't want to sort objects by camera distance.

If I just try to render the quads regularly with their transparent background, the result is that even the transparent pixels are written to the depth buffer, which cause a background bug see picture:

[image]

So I try to do it with a different way, using the stencil buffer. What I do is the following:

1. Render just the transparent pixels on the stencil buffer, to create a mask.
2. Render the texture itself, again, using the stencil buffer I created before.

Now it works with the background renderings, but the problem is that different quads with transparent background hide each other in transparent pixels, as seen here:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's because the stencil buffer is not cleared between renders or maybe in one of my steps I mistakenly write to depth?

Anyway here's my code (at least the relevant parts of it):

```
// set effect and settings for the stencil mask phase
_alphaMaskEffect = new AlphaTestEffect(device);
_alphaMaskEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
_alphaMaskEffect.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.Equal;
_alphaMaskEffect.ReferenceAlpha = 0;
_alphaMaskEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
_alphaMaskEffect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
_alphaRenderStencilMaskSettings = new DepthStencilState
{
    StencilEnable = true,
    StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Always,
    StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace,
    ReferenceStencil = 1,
    DepthBufferEnable = true,
    DepthBufferWriteEnable = false,
};

// set settings for the regular rendering phase
_alphaRenderTextureWithStencilSettings = new DepthStencilState
{
    StencilEnable = true,
    StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal,
    StencilPass = StencilOperation.Keep,
    ReferenceStencil = 0,
    DepthBufferEnable = true,
    DepthBufferWriteEnable = true,
};
```

And here's the draw function itself:

```
// set settings for the stencil buffer rendering
device.DepthStencilState = _alphaRenderStencilMaskSettings;

// render stencil buffer
foreach (EffectPass pass in _alphaMaskEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    // draw current pass
    pass.Apply();
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives
        <VertexPositionNormalTexture>(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
        Vertices, 0, 4,
        Indexes, 0, 2);
}

// now render the quad with the stencil buffer
device.DepthStencilState = _alphaRenderTextureWithStencilSettings;

// render effect itself
foreach (EffectPass pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    // draw current pass
    pass.Apply();
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives
        <VertexPositionNormalTexture>(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
        Vertices, 0, 4,
        Indexes, 0, 2);
}
```

**tl;dr** what's the right way to render 3d quads with transparent background, lighting and without sorting objects by distance from camera? And if it's the code I tried - how do I make the renderings stop hiding each other?

Comment: It's unclear to me why lighting would rule out using alpha testing. These are orthogonal concepts: you can use lighting in one part of your shader and alpha test in another part of the same shader, without conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Hey mate the best way to do it is with alpha test, that way no sorting but it still helps to sort and u can do lighting, render with opaque blend state, cull mode to none.

I do my grass like that, its just a quad with alpha test and then I build all the normal data in the shade. I also do use the vface semantic to flip the normal because its double sided.

alpha test in the pixel shader:

```
 diffuseLayer = DiffuseMaps.Sample(samANISOTROPICClamp, float3(input.TexCoord, input.TextureID));

clip(diffuseLayer.a - 0.18); // 0.18 is the alpha cut off, play with this
```

flipping the normal based on vface:

```
   float3 normalViewSpace = NormalMapToSpaceNormal(NormalLayer.rgb, TBN[2], TBN[1], TBN[0]);
normalViewSpace = input.vFace ? normalViewSpace : -normalViewSpace; // ignore the viewsapce stuff that is for my deferred render
```

Tangents and binormals in the shader based on a normal(N should be float3(0,1,0), UV should be the clip space xy, P should be world space positon:

```
float3x3 cotangent_frame(float3 N, float3 p, float2 uv)
{
// get edge vectors of the pixel triangle
float3 dp1 = ddx_fine(p);
float3 dp2 = ddy_fine(p);
float2 duv1 = ddx_fine(uv);
float2 duv2 = ddy_fine(uv);

// solve the linear system
float3 dp2perp = cross(dp2, N);
float3 dp1perp = cross(N, dp1);
float3 T = dp2perp * duv1.x + dp1perp * duv2.x;
float3 B = dp2perp * duv1.y + dp1perp * duv2.y;

// construct a scale-invariant frame 
float invmax =   -sqrt(max(dot(T, T), dot(B, B)));
return float3x3(T * invmax, B * invmax, N);
}
```

here is what the grass can look like:

[image]

CPU draw code(with dx 11 I don't have to set vertex buffers(runtime gens the points):

```
            _Context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, Nothing, Nothing)
        _Context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = Nothing

        _Context.OutputMerger.DepthStencilState = _device.RenderStates.Default
        _Context.Rasterizer.State = _device.RenderStates.CullNone
        _Context.SetBlendState(_device.RenderStates.Opaque)

        GrassEffectVars.Set("View", _camera.EyeTransform)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("Projection", _camera.ProjectionTransform)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("GrassNodes", GrassNodesView)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("DiffuseMaps", GrassTextureArraySRV)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("NormalMaps", GrassNormalTextureArraySRV)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("CameraTransform", _camera.Transform)

        GrassEffectVars.Set("gEyePosW", _camera.CameraBounds.Center)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("FarClip", _camera.FarClip)

        _Context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0)
        _Context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList

        GrassEffectVars.Set("InvView", _camera.Transform)
        GrassEffectVars.Set("WorldViewProj", _camera.EyeProjectionTransform)

        _Context.ApplyShader(GrassEffectPass2)
        _Context.DrawIndexedInstanced(6, GrassCount, 0, 0, 0)
```

Full grass shader as asked(builds quads from points):

```
struct PS_INPUT3
{
float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
uint TextureID : TextureID;
float4 Depth : VS_DEPTH;
bool vFace : SV_IsFrontFace;
};

PS_INPUT2 VS_Main2(uint id : SV_VertexID, uint instid : SV_InstanceId)
{
PS_INPUT2 output = (PS_INPUT2) 0;

uint particleIndex = id / 4;
uint vertexInQuad = id % 4;

GrassNode Grass = GrassNodes[instid];
float3 WS_Position = Grass.Pos.xyz;
float4 Data = Grass.Data;

float3 position;
position.x = (vertexInQuad % 2) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
position.y = (vertexInQuad & 2) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
position.z = 0.0;
position.xy *= Data.y;   

WS_Position.y += Data.y;
WS_Position.x += Data.z;
WS_Position.z += Data.w; 

position = mul(position, (float3x3) InvView) ;

WS_Position = WS_Position.xyz + position;

output.Depth.xyz = WS_Position;

output.Depth.w = mul(float4(WS_Position, 1), View).z;
output.Position = mul(float4(WS_Position.xyz, 1.0), WorldViewProj);    
output.TexCoord.x = (vertexInQuad % 2) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
output.TexCoord.y = (vertexInQuad & 2) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
output.TextureID = Data.x;
return output;
}

GBufferPixelShaderOutput PS_Main2(PS_INPUT3 input)
{

GBufferPixelShaderOutput output;
float4 diffuseLayer = 0;
float4 NormalLayer = 0;   

diffuseLayer += DiffuseMaps.Sample(samANISOTROPICClamp, float3(input.TexCoord, input.TextureID));

clip(diffuseLayer.a - 0.18);

NormalLayer += NormalMaps.Sample( samANISOTROPICClamp, float3(input.TexCoord, input.TextureID)) ;

float3x3 TBN = cotangent_frame(float3(0, 0.957, 0), input.Depth.xyz, input.Position.xy);

TBN[2] = normalize(mul(TBN[2], (float3x3) View));
TBN[0] = normalize(mul(TBN[0], (float3x3) View));
TBN[1] = normalize(mul(TBN[1], (float3x3) View));

float3 normalViewSpace = NormalMapToSpaceNormal(NormalLayer.rgb, TBN[2], TBN[1], TBN[0]);
normalViewSpace = input.vFace ? normalViewSpace : -normalViewSpace;
output.Color = float4(diffuseLayer.rgb,  diffuseLayer.r);

output.RenderMaterialID = matID;

output.Depth = float4(-input.Depth.w / FarClip, 0, EncodeNormal(normalViewSpace.xyz));

return output;

}
```

Comment: "the best way to do it is with alpha test" - my problem is not with normals (at least not yet :)) its with the fact that 'AlphaTestEffect' don't support lighting. or maybe I'm wrong? what kind of effect are you using? could you post the code that set device and draw the quads? thanks.

Comment: Alpha test works with lighting, you just need to write your own shaders, I used the pixel shader in XNA and just wrote the vextex shader to use the DX 11 features 

I updated my answer with CPU side code and the shaders I use.

PS. I use alpha test for the leaves on my tress so it 100% works with lighting

Comment: I'm happy u find my post of help, if I can add anymore plz feel free to ask :)